# Is belonging not defined in axiomatic set theory?

Tags: set-theory

In *Naive Set Theory*, Halmos states the following:

> The principal concept of set theory, the one that in completely axiomatic studies is the principal primitive (undefined) concept, is that of *belonging*.

I'm surprised. Is $\in$ really not defined in axiomatic studies?

Comment: No; it is a *primitive notion*. You describe its properties, you don't say what it *is*. That's the nature of axiomatic theory: you have a bunch of undefined notions, and some axioms about how they behave and what their properties are.

Comment: It is not defined.This gives great flexibility. For example Russell's Paradox  is that it is illogical to  assert the existence of a widget $W$ that digs every widget that does not dig itself and does not dig any widget that digs itself. (Replace "widget" with "set" and "dig(s)" with "has as a member"). It doesn't matter what widgets are or what "dig(s)" means.

Comment: See [The Frege-Hilbert Controversy](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/frege-hilbert/) for a discussion between founding fathers of modern axiomatic method.