# Am I correct in understanding Axiom of Extension?

Tags: logic, set-theory, predicate-logic

Halmos mentions the following:

> **Axiom of extension:** Two sets are equal ***if and only*** [emphasized] if they have the same elements.

My understanding of Axiom of Extension as presented above is as following:
Axiom of Extension is **independent** of the [Axioms of Equality](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-order_logic#Equality_and_its_axioms) in first-order logic with equality. A set might (or must *always*?) also have an *intension* which determines its *extension*. So two equal sets (by Equality Axioms) **logically implies** that they must have the **same** intension *as well as* extension, *doesn’t it?* Now, Axiom of Extension makes a ***logically unprovable*** remark that a set’s extension is all that matters.

Please fix my understanding.

---

Also, is “if and only if” required in Halmos’ statement? Cuz according to Jech,

> If $X$ and $Y$ have the same elements, then $X=Y$ …
>   The converse … is an axiom of predicate calculus.

I’ve never come across this axiom. So help!

Comment: "I’ve never come across this axiom." Yes, you have. You just cited it. It's an instance of the substitution for formulas axiom.

Comment: Does first-order logic then include the notion of *belonging*?

Comment: Oh! I just realized that we ***can*** include $\in$ as a binary relation.

Comment: But then, $\in$ is the “principal primitive notion” in axiomatic set theory (see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3257748/is-belonging-not-defined-in-axiomatic-set-theory).

Comment: So how can we *define* $\in$ within first-order logic?

Comment: See also the post [What is the standard first-order language to formalize ZFC?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3126277/what-is-the-standard-first-order-language-to-formalize-zfc)

Comment: "Axiom of Extension makes a logically unprovable remark that a set’s extension is all that matters." What does it mean "logically unprovable" ? The axiom is called Extensionality Ax exactly because it formalize the idea that what matters in "identifying" a set are exactly its elements (i.e. its extension).

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA By “logically unprovable”, I mean that it can’t be a logical consequence.

Comment: It is a mathematical axiom, i.e. it is not a "logical truth" i.e. a valid formula (true in every interpretation).

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Can we *define* $\in$?

Comment: No; in axiomatic set theory $\in$ is a primitive symbol (the only one except $=$, in the case of predicate logic with equality). Its meaning is "descrbed" the theory through the axioms.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Got it! Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> According to Jech, the converse of the Extensionalty Axiom "is an axiom of predicate calculus."

If the underlying logic is [predicate calculus **with** equality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-order_logic#Equality_and_its_axioms), we have the *substitution axiom for formulas* :

> $x = y → (\varphi → \varphi')$,

where $\varphi'$ is obtained by replacing any number of free occurrences of $x$ in $\varphi$ with $y$.

Thus, considering the formula $(z \in x)$ as $\varphi$, we have :

> $x=y \to (z \in x \to z \in y)$.

Comment: Please see the comments.